# Rings: how to study them?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Which are the features that make a ring different from another?

For example Is there a difference between $54\mathbb Z$ and $106\mathbb Z$?

Is there something special for the Rings $p\mathbb Z$ where p Is a prime. And what Is the role of modules in studying a ring?

Comment: Modules are to rings what vector spaces are to fields. Much of what we know about vector spaces generalizes to modules. Prime ideals are central to the study of rings, even in more exotic settings than $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: The sets you are referring to are not rings because they don't have a multiplicative identity.

Comment: @mathlander, it is very hard to know what a ring is and not that people study both rings with identity and without one...

Comment: This question seems a bit too broad, so people might vote to close it. The question "what are the features that make a ring different from another" can be answered by, like, ten textbooks' worth of ring theory (and probably more). Consider making it more specific to get a good answer --- what type of response are you looking for? And give some context -- why are you asking this question?

Comment: There is a term for "ring without identity", it is called a rng.

Comment: I have never in my life used that term. There are books where rings by default do not have identities and in which rng would be nothing but a typo, and so on. There is no point in dragging this...

Comment: The question «what is the purpose of modules?» has surely been asked in one form or another. The question abouit $54Z$ ansd $106Z$ is, on the other hand,. both interesting and probably new.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose that $n$ is a positive integer, and consider $R=n\mathbb Z$ as a non-unitary ring. We can form $R^2$, the subgroup of $R$ generated by all products of two elements in $R$, and consider the quotient abelian group $R/R^2$.

Does $R/R^2$ give you some information about the number $n$?

Comment: This is one way to study rings, if you want to tell them apart: you find *invariants*, things that are preserved under isomorphism. Modules provide a very useful way to construct invariants for rings.